# Per example clipping in TensorFlow Federated with DP-FedAvg

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I'm trying to train a differentially private federated model using EMNIST dataset, I have attached the `DP-Query` to the `aggregation_process`. Moreover, I'm resembling the `DP-FedAvg` algorithm by using `SGD` as both client and server optimizer with server learning rate set to 1.

The query is:

```
dp_query = tff.utils.build_dp_query(
    clip=0.6
    noise_multiplier=1.2,
    expected_total_weight=100,
    adaptive_clip_learning_rate=0,
    target_unclipped_quantile=0.5,
    clipped_count_budget_allocation=0.1,
    expected_clients_per_round=100
)
```

What type of clipping does this query perform, is it *batch clipping*, or *per example clipping*?

In `TFP`, the option to use the per example clipping was to set the `num_microbatches` to `None` so it defaults to the `batch_size`.

How can I do something similar here, and switch between the batch clipping and per example clipping in Federated settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DPQuery only specifies *how* to clip, it doesn't specify *what* is clipped. In a federated context, the entire client update is clipped. You could say that each client's update functions similarly to a microbatch in the centralized (non-federated) context. This provides a strong "user level" DP guarantee. There wouldn't much utility in grouping clients into "client microbatches".

Comment: You might want to check out `tff.aggregators.DifferentiallyPrivateFactory.gaussian_fixed` which is a simpler way to construct an aggregation process with the options you're using.